# Sending files over Socket (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, file, sockets, ios5

I created a Socket based Simple Chat app. 
The Post: [Socket Based iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) helped me create this.

I now want to send/receive files over the socket.
Please give me pointers as to how I can go about to achieve this.

Cheers,
Roshit

**EDIT:**

Code used to connect to socket is :

```
NSString *aHostName = @"xx.xx.xx.xx";
NSInteger aPort = 1234;

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)aHostName, aPort, &readStream, &writeStream);

self.inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
self.outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
[self.outputStream setDelegate:self];

[self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[self.inputStream open];
[self.outputStream open];
```

Code used to send data is

```
NSData *aData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[iRequestAPI dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[self.outputStream write:[aData bytes] maxLength:[aData length]];
[aData release];
```

where, iRequestAPI is the string that has to be sent.

Now when I try sending a file over socket, considering the fact I convert the File into NSData and use `[self.outputStream write:[aData bytes] maxLength:[aData length]];` can there be a possibility that the entire file is not sent due to connection bandwidth. 
If the entire file is not sent, how to ensure the rest of it is sent.

Is this the right approach to send a file over socket. 
Please suggest..

Comment: This question is too vague.  You need to be more specific about what part you're having trouble with.  Do you know how to open and read from files?  Do you know how to extend your protocol to support sending files?

Comment: Nope. I really dont know anything related to file handling when it comes to sockets. The file that I have to send is saved in the Documents Directory of the App.

Comment: I asked a question for which I did not get a satisfactory explanation anywhere. Really dont see the necessity for having down voted... If you have down voted you must be having a good answer to this or atleast a pointer to the solution. Down vote isnt my concern. Someone pls gimme a solution.

Comment: wtf.... y cant ppl comment when they down vote... I do want to know the reason....

Answer (score 2):

If your NSData is big enough you need to cut it into pieces.You'll need bytes to transfer them .For example:

```
NSData *newData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]);
    int index = 0;
    int totalLen = [newData length];
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[newData bytes];

    while (index < totalLen) {
        if ([outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
            int indexLen =  (1024>(totalLen-index))?(totalLen-index):1024;

            (void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, indexLen);

            int written = [outputStream write:buffer maxLength:indexLen];

            if (written < 0) {
                break;
            }

            index += written;

            readBytes += written;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Files contain data. Network connections (socket or otherwise) transfer data. You *could* just open the file, read the data, and start writing that very same data to your socket. However...

You probably want to transfer the file *within the context of the chat session*. So, you're going to want to delimit the file somehow, so that the receiving end of the connection realizes that the data coming across is a file. And you'll probably want to transfer some metadata for the file, such as name, size, etc.

Exactly *how* you do all that is entirely up to you. You're writing the code at both ends of the connection, so if you come up with a plan and implement it properly, you should be able to make it work. One approach would use some magic string, like `+++++++++++++` to delimit the start of the file information. If you specify the number of bytes, then you can write that many bytes to the connection and expect the other side to read that many bytes. Another way to do it would be to convert your entire data stream to include meta-information. For example, you could use an XML-based format.

It's really up to you.

Comment: I did create a JSON format with the data of the file and some metadata. But for some reason the writing never stopped. I assume the  entire data to be sent was not written in the first write and it continued to wait for the next set of data. Seems like I have to figure out a way to send the rest of the data.